# How to batch convert m4a files to mp3 using ffmpeg?

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, batch-file, cmd.exe

In Windows, how can I batch convert m4a files to mp3 using ffmpeg ?
I use the following line in the command line:

```
FOR I in (*.m4a) DO ffmpeg -i %I -codec:v copy -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 "mp3\%I"
```

But I get the error "I is not expected at this moment".

Comment: could you try to replace `FOR I` by `FOR %I` ?

Comment: @S.Brottes I get the error "Transaction: No such file or directory".

Comment: does the subdirectory `mp3` exist?

Comment: Yes, the subdir exists.

Answer (score 0):

I find Powershell much more legible for code like this, and you're using Windows anyways so Powershell is built-in to your OS.

For example, I have my albums organized `artist\album\title.mp3`

This is a slightly-generalized version of the script I just wrote to solve the same problem:

```
#assume the current directory is my music directory. So like `cd ~/music` or whatever.

$ffmpegPath = 'c:\tools\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe' # or you can just call ffmpeg.exe directly if it's in the $Env:PATH

ls *.m4a -Recurse | foreach-object {
  $artist = $_.directory.parent.name
  $album = $_.directory.name
  $song = $_.baseName
  $outputDir = "./output/$artist/$album"
  mkdir $outputDir -Force | Out-Null #use -Force to prevent error if it already exists.

  & $ffmpegPath -i $_ -codec:v copy -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 "$outputDir/$song.mp3"
}
```